# Windows phone 7- Loading an existing Database into isolated storage

Tags: database, windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage

How do I load an existing database with lots of data in it, to isolated storage. I have read little of how to use database in phone 7 but they don't load any predefined data. Instead they create a database if it is running for the first time later use the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add a database to your project, but it can only be used in read-only mode.  If you want to read/write to it, you have to add code that will copy the data to a separate database after install.

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/10/01/linq-to-sql-on-windows-phone-75.aspx
From that article:

> Using an Existing Database It's possible to ship an existing database
>   with your application by adding it to your project and setting the
>   Build Action to Content. This will deploy the database file with your
>   application onto the phone, but it will be placed in the same folder
>   as all other static content for your application. Your application can
>   only read from this folder, which means you either have to open the
>   database in read-only mode, or copy the database across into Isolated
>   Storage before accessing it. The following is an example connection
>   string for a database that's been packaged with the application:

Comment: Abhay - note that if you need to read/write, you will need to copy the database to isostore.  If your database is large, and you need to copy it, consider the impact of a person with an 8GB phone, and having your database on their phone twice, and can't get rid of the duplicate.  If this is a concern, consider placing your data on a server, create a web service, and download the data on first run. Be sure to notify the user that this is happening, and be sure to allow it to continue on a subsequent run, should the download get interrupted by a phone call, text, key press, or other event.

Comment: If you do not need to write to the database, you do not need to make the duplicate in isostore.